# PHP save image in mysql cause image broken

Tags: php, mysql, blob

I have a PHP script to save an uploaded image.  It worked before, but it did not work last week.

```
$cidimg = base64_decode( $_POST[ 'image' ] );
insertCustomerImage( $db,
                     $cid,
                     $cidimg );

function insertCustomerImage( $db,
                              $cid,
                              $cidimg )
{
    try
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO customer_images ( cid,
                                              cidimg )
                VALUES ( :cid, :cidimg )
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cid = :cid,
                                        cidimg =: cidimg,
                                        created = Now()";

        $query = $db -> prepare( $sql );
        $query -> execute( array( ':cid' => $cid,
                                  ':cidimg' => $cidimg, ) );                    

    }
    catch( PDOException $e )
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

It can insert the image string into MySQL as a `BLOB`.  But when read it again, it show empty.  As below (not a valid JPEG header) :

```
????JFIF??C  %# , #&')*)
```

Comment: I can find the binary data in mysql begin with:    3f3f 3f3f 0010 4a46 4946 0001 0100 0001                                                                                                   but the valid binary data for image in mysql should begin with:  ffd8 ffe0 0010 4a46 4946 0001 0101 0060

Comment: Is `':cidimg' => $cidimg,` meant to be followed by a comma?

Comment: Is there any validation requiring the content type to be jpg? or can I rename a gif file to `.jpg` and will this still try work? If so do you do any content type validation when displaying the image, or do you just send a jpg header?

Comment: Hi toonice, remove that comma still not working. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Dave, Because I upload that image from Android, I encode it base64 format and then decode it into mysql as blob. The image data after inserted into mysql  its jpg header is broken.  I try remove utf-8 bom but nothing happen.

Comment: Hi Dave, if i just insert the base64 encode data into mysql blob, and then query from mysql and decode it in php. I can get a image showed. So i think the base64 image string is valid.  If i just insert the decode base64 data into mysql blob, and then output it, the image can not showed. And the image data string is a mess.

Comment: ????JFIF??C  %# , #&')*)-0-(0%()(??C   (((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((???0"?? ???}!1AQa"q2???#B??R??$3br?

Answer (score 0):

after long time checking, figure it out. Because I have change pdo character in other sub function.

$db->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

So the PDO changed the image string decode when insert into mysql as blob.

I just uncomment this line. Everything runs well. Cheers!